# Insert new record into a table with composite primary key

Tags: mysql, sql

This question may be very simple but I have been struggling to find a solution. Here is what I have, table order with two composite primary key (order_id, order_detail_id). This is just for an illustration purpose but my prd table is of the same concept.

Order

```
order_id | order_detail_id | order_name
```

My question is how to insert a new record with an existing order_id. Let's say these are the rows existing,

```
1 | 1 | 'Order 1 Detail 1'
1 | 2 | 'Order 1 Detail 2'
2 | 1 | 'Order 2 Detail 1'
```

Now I want to a new order detail into the existing order 1. I use Mysql 5 with InnoDB. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: If you are inserting a new record for order_id = 1 wouldn't order_detail_id = 3? the primary key would still be unique.

Comment: @GB Yes the order_detail_id is going to be 3 but I don't know what exists in the DB and in the run time i want that to be managed.

Comment: Before the insert you could just `select max(order_detail_id) from order where order_id = (your_order_id))` then just add one to that, then insert?

Comment: Thanks GB i found out a soln

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into order 
    select order_id, max(order_detail_id) + 1, 'Order 1 Detail 3' 
    where order_id=1
```

Comment: It won't be a question of *if* but rather *when* this will cause problems for you. Create an auto increment on your order_detail table and if you really need line_numbers then assign them on `select`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.